# Rename edit string if not first in index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have pandas dataframe, containing information in the following format:

| sentence_num | sent_word | tag | word_char | word_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | B-foo | f | 1 |
| 0 | foo | B-foo | o | 1 |
| 0 | foo | B-foo | o | 1 |
| 0 | [ ] | B-ws | [ ] | 2 |
| 0 | bar | B-bar | b | 3 |
| 0 | bar | B-bar | a | 3 |
| 0 | bar | B-bar | r | 3 |
| 1 | john | B-name | j | 1 |
| 1 | john | B-name | o | 1 |
| 1 | john | B-name | h | 1 |
| 1 | john | B-name | n | 1 |
| 1 | [ ] | B-ws | [ ] | 2 |
| 1 | doe | B-sur | d | 3 |
| 1 | doe | B-sur | o | 3 |
| 1 | doe | B-sur | e | 3 |

I want to rename tags if the char is not the first in the word:

| sentence_num | sent_word | tag | word_char | word_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo | B-foo | f | 1 |
| 0 | foo | **I-foo** | o | **1** |
| 0 | foo | **I-foo** | o | **1** |
| 0 | [ ] | B-ws | [ ] | 2 |
| 0 | bar | B-bar | b | 3 |
| 0 | bar | **I-bar** | a | **3** |
| 0 | bar | **I-bar** | r | **3** |
| 1 | john | B-name | j | 1 |
| 1 | john | **I-name** | o | **1** |
| 1 | john | **I-name** | h | **1** |
| 1 | john | **I-name** | n | **1** |
| 1 | [ ] | B-ws | [ ] | 2 |
| 1 | doe | B-sur | d | 3 |
| 1 | doe | **I-sur** | o | **3** |
| 1 | doe | **I-sur** | e | **3** |

Since the word index is repeating and the sentence num does not help me a lot, I am not sure how to group the data so that I get to the elements I want to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is word_char not the first letter?
# and sent_word is not "[ ]"
m = ( df['sent_word'].str[0].ne(df['word_char']) 
    & df['sent_word'].ne('[ ]')
    )

# for those rows, change the B into I
df.loc[m, 'tag'] = 'I'+df.loc[m, 'tag'].str[1:]
```

output:

```
    sentence_num sent_word     tag word_char  word_index
0              0       foo   B-foo         f           1
1              0       foo   I-foo         o           1
2              0       foo   I-foo         o           1
3              0       [ ]    B-ws       [ ]           2
4              0       bar   B-bar         b           3
5              0       bar   I-bar         a           3
6              0       bar   I-bar         r           3
7              1      john  B-name         j           1
8              1      john  I-name         o           1
9              1      john  I-name         h           1
10             1      john  I-name         n           1
11             1       [ ]    B-ws       [ ]           2
12             1       doe   B-sur         d           3
13             1       doe   I-sur         o           3
14             1       doe   I-sur         e           3
```

Comment: `.ne?`, also I don't want to change it for the 'one char' element, such as the empty space.

Comment: @Yana `na` = not equal (`!=`), and see update for "[ ]"

Comment: @Yana so does it work as you want?

Comment: Yes, I had to make a little change because I did not explain it very well. It is not because I want to preserve the whitespace, but the tag which is 'B-ws'. The latter could be linked to other symbols. So the part after the `&` is & `df['tag'].ne('B-ws')`. Thank you, again. It was really helpful and simple solution.